# Spring logging facility setting to enable capturing IP address of ldap host being authenticated against?

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, ldap, log4j

We use a form of round robin load balancing across about 20 LDAP servers utilizing DNS.  Basically just an A record with a short TTL that contains the IP addresses of all the aforementioned LDAP servers, in this context I will refer to it as 'ldap.test.com'.

The scenario/issue here is one of our release management tools utilizes spring-security to perform authentication via ldap and/or active directory.  Apparently there is an issue with one, or possibly two of the ldap servers contained within the host record ldap.test.com as we occasionally get an authentication failure.
The error shown in the logs unfortunately does not provide the actual IP of the specific server rejecting the connection, it only prints the hostname, eg:

*javax.naming.CommunicationException: ldap.test.com:389 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]*

I have attempted turning up every known logging facility via log4j for spring and spring-security to no avail.  So my question being, is there a possible method to configure logging to output the host IP currently being utilized from the A record?